# Allure reporting issue with testng and maven, java selenium

Tags: java, maven, allure

I have updated my pom.xml as per [link](https://seleniumjava.com/2015/10/15/create-selenium-webdriver-html-reports-with-the-allure-framework/).

But only `xml` files are getting created under folder 'allure-results'.

No `index.html` file is created for the executed test cases.

I was also searching for testng listeners for allure reporting. But unable to find the same.

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan , Do you have any idea about the above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the report generation tools to generate the report from xml results. In your case `allure-maven-plugin` is already configured in `pom.xml`. So simply run `mvn site` to generate the report. For more information see [the docs](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki#generating-a-report).

Comment: Now getting: [ERROR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.register(ZZI)V‌​[ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.properties.decorators.DefaultFieldDecorato‌​r.<init>(DefaultFiel‌​dDecorator.java:24) [ERROR] at ru.yandex.qatools.properties.PropertyLoader.populate(Propert‌​yLoader.java:29) I am sorry to say, but i did not find a single page where the complete information with steps to be followed is present to generate the allure report. There are so many pages and information is present in chunks.

Comment: you can find the compete example here https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-junit-example